# How to open a eshell buffer in a different window in doom emacs?

Tags: eshell, doom

I want to open an eshell buffer in right side of the current window in the same frame.

Comment: Welcome.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Doom Emacs, I assume you have access to `evil` commands. The following command may be your solution.

```
(defun right-side-eshell ()
  "Open an eshell window in the right side."
  (interactive)
  (evil-window-vsplit)
  (evil-window-right 1)
  (eshell))
```

Alternatively you can use `split-window-right` and `other-window` instead of `evil-window-vsplit` and `evil-window-right`. This will make `right-side-eshell` independent of `evil`. Note that if you have more than one active window, this simple command might not create the `eshell` buffer exactly at the right place.

Then, you can bind this command to whatever you like using `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c e") 'right-side-eshell)`.